# jQuery plugin not processing disabled property on option tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

My .net website is using a jQuery plugin; I have the following code on a simple .aspx page:

```
<select id="Select2" name="categoryFilter">
    <option class="inactiveLabel" value="A" disabled="disabled">A</option>
    <option value="x">x</option>
    <option class="inactiveLabel" value="B" disabled="disabled">B</option>
    <option value="y">y</option>
    <option class="inactiveLabel" value="C" disabled="disabled">C</option>
    <option value="z">z</option>
    <option class="inactiveLabel" value="D" disabled="disabled">D</option>
    <option value="w">w</option>
    <option class="inactiveLabel" value="E" disabled="disabled">E</option>
    <option value="t">t</option>
</select>
```

When I load the page in a browser, the jquery plugin adds a style="display: none;" property on the < select > tag and converts the above code to the below, which in turn shows up on the page:

```
<a class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-selectmenu-dropdown inactiveLabel ui-state-active ui-corner-top" 
    id="Select2-button" role="button" href="#" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="Select2-menu" style="width: 120px;">
            <span class="ui-selectmenu-status">x</span>
            <span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a>
```

...

```
<ul class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown ui-selectmenu-open" 
    aria-hidden="false" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="Select2-button" id="Select2-menu" style="width: 120px; top: 158px; left: 316px;" 
    aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-410">

    <li role="presentation" class="inactiveLabel ui-selectmenu-item-selected">
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="ui-selectmenu-item-410">A</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">x</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="inactiveLabel">
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">B</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">y</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="inactiveLabel">
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">C</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="">
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">z</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="inactiveLabel">
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">D</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">w</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="inactiveLabel">
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">E</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="ui-corner-bottom">
            <a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">t</a>
    </li></ul>
```

The problem is, the jQuery plugin that converts the code ignores the disabled="disabled" property on the < option > tags of the original code, so all  tags end up being enabled.  None of the original disabled="disabled" properties are reflected in the new code that's produced by the jQuery plugin and spit out on the page.  How can I make sure certain option tags are disabled?

Comment: Which jQuery plugin are you using? It's a function in the plugin that's rewriting it without the disabled.

Comment: Your plugin must provide this functionality, otherwise you have to handle it manually